Deploy resources to AWS through Terraform using Harness CI/CD
Can anyone tell how to create a terraform pipeline in harness so that I can deploy resources to AWS?
Thanks
I tried CI and CD options in harness but could not deploy.
I have also added AWS connector but it does help.
Harness documentation is so bad

Isn't https://developer.harness.io/docs/category/terraform help?
